# How to change separator in a list from "," to ";" not using the join function or any list operations

Tags: python

I have to set a method that returns a string from the content of a given object. I am able to make the string of the list of numbers but my professor wants the separator between each element to be a semicolon instead of a comma, which I am having trouble doing. I tried using the join function but I then realized that my professor does not want to use any list operations like `len` or `in` besides append and reading and writing to an index .

I have already tried to concatenate the semicolon to the string but of course, that only concatenates the semicolon at the end of the string and doesn't separates each element with a semicolon.

Here is my code

```
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, lst=[], size = 0):
    self.L = lst
    self.size = size
  def addLast(self, x):
    self.L.append(x)
    self.size += 1
  def removeFirst(self):
    L = self.L
    p = L[1:]
    return p
  def __str__(self):
    result = ''
    result += str(self.L)
    return result
```

Using this as a test case, you can see that it prints out as [1, 2, 3] instead of "[1;2;3]"

```
lst = LinkedList()
print(lst) # prints []
print(lst.size) # prints 0
lst.addLast(1)
lst.addLast(2)
print(lst.size) # prints 2
lst.addLast(3)
print(lst) # this should print "[1;2;3]"
```

Comment: Why do you call your class `LinkedList` when there are no links?

Comment: @Barmar this is only part of the class that is needed to make my specific problem work, since I can't do the rest of the Class until I fix this problem

Comment: There is a shortcut: return result.replace(“,”,”;”)

Comment: @Tim That won't work well if any of the elements contain `,` characters.

Comment: @user10336367 The reason I ask is because iterating through a linked list is different from iterating through an indexed data structure. So if you change it to a real linked list, you won't be able to use the answers.

Comment: It’s linked list in the sense that you can only add to end or remove first. Perhaps what you need are the following. 1. Two methods: one for reading the first and one for getting the last element. 2. you need a “next” method to get the next element given any element. Then, you don’t need any list operations. I think your prof is trying to each you how linked list works without using built-in list operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to concatenate the list elements, appending `;` between each.

```
def __str__(self):
    result = '['
    if self.size > 0:
        result += str(self.L[0]) # print first element normally
        for item in self.L[1:]: # print the rest, preceding each with ';'
            result += ';' + str(item)
    result += ']'
    return result
```

If you're not allowed to use `for-in`, you can use a `while` loop.

```
def __str__(self):
    result = '['
    if self.size > 0:
        result += str(self.L[0]) # print first element normally
        i = 1
        while i < self.size
            result += ';' + str(self.L[i])
            i += 1
    result += ']'
    return result
```

Comment: I edited my post to mention I can't use functions like len or "in," would the for loop be considered part of the "in" function? @Barmar

Comment: We are currently learning OOP, but in the PDF it says that by not using "len" and "in" and just using append, reading and writing to an index is to "get a feel for what it was like to code in the good ol' days before Object oriented languages were around."

Comment: I've replaced the `for` loop with `while`.